# How to change Bootstrap Multiselect Checkbox and radiobox to pretty?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the bootstrap multiselect plugin. An example is http://www.bootply.com/cEjepVhvjg.

Now I want to change the CSS style of checkbox and radio button inside multiselect box to http://www.cssscript.com/demo/pretty-checkbox-radio-inputs-with-bootstrap-and-awesome-bootstrap-checkbox-css/

How can I change? I tried some CSS changes but not worked.

```
.checkbox label::before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 17px;
    height: 17px;
    /* left: 0; */
    margin-left: -20px;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-transition: border 0.15s ease-in-out, color 0.15s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: border 0.15s ease-in-out, color 0.15s ease-in-out;
    transition: border 0.15s ease-in-out, color 0.15s ease-in-out;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: `I tried some CSS changes but not worked.` What did you try?

Comment: I need pretty checkbox within that dropdown

Comment: try like this http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/fancy-bootstrap-checkboxes

Comment: these are 2 different things not related to each other. What is your problem?